# What is the probability a specific video in a loop is played while a customer waits in line?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

Question: What is the probability a given video from a video loop will be displayed to a customer waiting in line?

Assumptions:
 1. Mean Wait Time = 260 Seconds
 2. Standard Deviation of Wait = 120 Seconds (assumed normal distribution for simplicity, though likely has fat tails!)
 3. Number of videos in loop = 32
 4. Time of Video = 6 seconds + 1 second between video plays
 5. Video should count as "Viewed" even if only partially seen by customer (i.e. if customer sees the only the first second of video, it should count as viewed).
 6. The order videos in the loop are played can effectively be considered random, as the loop does NOT restart from customer to customer.

Background: 
I am developing a reach forecasting model that uses the probability a customer views a given advertisement as one of its inputs.

I've been able to solve this via simulation (should be ~87% for the assumptions described above), but I would like to understand and employ the math to make the model more flexible and not dependent on simulation.

Thank you!!

Comment: The answer depends *heavily* on the distribution of the shorter waiting times.  Due to the lower limit of zero, that is unlikely to be well approximated by a Normal tail, so I would suggest investing more effort into researching this distribution compared to obtaining theoretical (but unrealistic) answers based on invalid assumptions.

Comment: Your point is a good one and well taken. Unfortunately I only possess the summary statistics (i.e. mean & deviation) of wait time and not the data itself, otherwise I would be able to fit a more appropriate distribution. Until I can go out and collect the data myself, I'm just looking for a rough approximation. Also, I found myself curious about how the math would work _if_ a normal distribution were appropriate. In my simulation, I did of course implement a zero lower bound on wait time.

Comment: I'd suggest that you at least consider the characteristics of wait time. Is wait time likely to be a mix of 0 wait (when the queue is empty) and some longer wait? Is there some minimum service time (so that if you hit a queue with multiple people waiting to be served the lower limit on wait time will be well above 0?) Is there a "typical" service time that most services approximately  or can they be almost any length?